# Canvas javascript animation - rect running from left to right changing color - animation repeat problem

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have wrote a code for my recruitment task - it must me a recktangle moving from the left to the right. When it hits to the right bound it should changes its size to 100px, left bound is 50px. After every 20px it is changing its color. How can I ensure this change is going once fo every 20pxls?
The code is actually running properly, but I cannot find any solution on the internet that helps me to repeat this concrete code animation. It is going from the left to the right and then to the left again and reck is hiding like going infinite left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CANVAS animacje</title>
    <style>
    
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
   
    </style>
</head>
<body>

   <canvas></canvas>
<script>

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 500;

let cw = canvas.width;
let ch = canvas.height;

let canvasX = 0;
let canvasY = 0;

let rectX = 0;
let rectY = ch/2;

let rectSize = 50;
let rectSizeRight = 100;
let rectSpeed = 10;

function field(){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
    ctx.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, cw, ch);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(field);

}

function randomColors(){
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(randomColors);

    }


function rect(){

    ctx.fillStyle = randomColors()
    ctx.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectSize,rectSize);
    
    rectX+=rectSpeed; 

    
    if(rectX+rectSize == 0){
        rectSize = rectSize;
        rectSpeed=rectSpeed;
    } else if(rectX+rectSizeRight == cw){
        rectSize=rectSizeRight;
        rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    } ;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(rect);

    
    // if(rectX+rectSizeRight == cw){
    //     rectSize=rectSizeRight;
    //     rectSpeed = -rectSpeed
    //   } 

    

    
    //   if (rectX+rectSize <= 0){
    //       rectSize = rectSize;
    //       rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    //   }
    //   if(rectX+rectSizeRight>=cw){
    //       rectSize=rectSizeRight;
    //       rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    //   }
     }


 function animate(){
field();
rect();
randomColors();
 }

 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the long story short:

- remove redundant calls to functions that render things on screen
- store last picked colors to reference them after canvas background
  overrides the rectangle
- change colors only when x coordinates are multiple of 20 (use modulo operator to check that)
- code after `return` won't be executed

Here's the updated code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 500;

let cw = canvas.width;
let ch = canvas.height;

let canvasX = 0;
let canvasY = 0;

let rectX = 0;
let rectY = ch/2;

let rectSize = 50;
let rectSizeRight = 100;
let rectSpeed = 1;

// my change
let currentColors = randomColors();

function field(){

    ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
    ctx.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, cw, ch);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(field);

}

function randomColors() {

        let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);

        return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';

    }


function rect(){

    // my change
    if (rectX % 20 === 0) {
        currentColors = randomColors();
    }

    // my change
    ctx.fillStyle = currentColors;

    ctx.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectSize,rectSize);

    rectX+=rectSpeed; 


    if(rectX+rectSize == 0){
        rectSize = rectSize;
        rectSpeed=rectSpeed;
    } else if(rectX+rectSizeRight == cw){
        rectSize=rectSizeRight;
        rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    } ;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(rect);


    // if(rectX+rectSizeRight == cw){
    //     rectSize=rectSizeRight;
    //     rectSpeed = -rectSpeed
    //   } 




    //   if (rectX+rectSize <= 0){
    //       rectSize = rectSize;
    //       rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    //   }
    //   if(rectX+rectSizeRight>=cw){
    //       rectSize=rectSizeRight;
    //       rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
    //   }
     }


 function animate(){
    // my change
    field();
    rect();
 }

 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Besides that, code is a bit messy but that's a different story.

Comment: Thank you much, that helps me a lot, I got this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kk42qx?embed=1&file=index.ts

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;


const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 500;

let cw = canvas.width;
let ch = canvas.height;

let canvasX = 0;
let canvasY = 0;

let rectX = 0;
let rectY = ch/2;

let rectSize = 50;
let rectSizeRight = 100;
let rectSpeed = 10;

function field(){
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
  ctx.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, cw, ch);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(field);
}

function randomColors(){
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(randomColors);
}

let a = 0; <==== Initialize a variable outside the loop

function rect(){

  a++; <=== 

  ctx.fillStyle = randomColors()
  ctx.fillRect(rectX,rectY,rectSize,rectSize);

  // ==========================
  if (a % 50 === 0) {
    rectX = a;
  }
  // ==========================


  if(rectX + rectSize == 0){
    rectSize = rectSize;
    rectSpeed = rectSpeed;
  } else if(rectX + rectSizeRight === cw){
    rectSize = rectSizeRight;
    rectSpeed = -rectSpeed;
  } else if (1) {

  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(rect);

  // console.log(rectX)

}



function animate(){
  field();
  rect();
  randomColors();
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```